# How to get the file size before downloading

Tags: c++, download, wininet

I am trying to download a binary file from a http: server. I am using the functions `InternetOpenUrl()` and then `InternetReadFile()` to download the file. Is it possible to know the size of the file before downloading?.

Thanks
Vinod

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`HttpQueryInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384238%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `HTTP_QUERY_CONTENT_LENGTH` for this, although the server is not required to send the content length and so you should not rely on this.

Comment: Note that this is not required to work -- the HTTP server is not required to send the content length. Your code must not rely on this.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to call [`InternetGetLastResponseInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384717%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) after the call to `InternetOpenUrl` to get the response headers. Those should (most likely) contain the `content-length` of the file.